# How to deploy helm chart (that are stored as images) using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, kubernetes-helm

I have stored the custom made helm charts (Elasticsearch, Longhorn) in the gitlab container registry as images. How can I deploy the helm chart to a kubernetes environment using Ansible?

Comment: I am quite new to Ansible, any useful links/documentation that could potentially help me is welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of Ansible module to deploy a helm charts for example you can follow this links where you can find a lot of example:

- https://www.ansible.com/blog/automating-helm-using-ansible
- [https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/helm_module.html](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/helm_module.html)

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue .

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped! :)